# Property configuration of java classes in groovy script with spring

Tags: java, spring, groovy

I want to use Groovy scripts to utilize some java classes that are have spring annotations along the lines of the following:

```
@Component
class SomeUtility {
    @Value("${foo}")
    public string String fooValue;
}
```

Ideally I would like to configure `foo` in an `application.properties` file in the same manner as done in spring-boot

I have tried adding spring to the classpath and running something like this in a groovy script:

```
def ctx = new GenericApplicationContext()
new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(ctx).scan('dylan')
ctx.refresh()
def b = ctx.getBean(SomeUtility)
println b.fooValue
```

but the output is `${foo}` whether a properties file is in place or not - so I guess the @Value value processing is not happening.

I have also tried adding spring-boot to the classpath and running the above script - but I suspect I am not actually triggering spring-boot in that case.

Is there any way that I can do this - what I want is essentially to be able to configure the values easily then get hold of the components in a groovy script.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Groovy, you need to do single quote `@Value('${foo}')`, as double quotes will be picked up by Groovy as a GString before Spring has a chance to look at its own context.

Comment: The annotation is on a java class so I cannot use the single quotes - it is only the script that is in groovy.

Comment: I see, it seems you are loading ApplicationContext manually. Spring Boot works since it loads a ConfigFileListener before application context starts to configure itself. In your case, you will need to load the properties file yourself, try something like `ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource)`, where propertySource is a `PropertiesPropertySource`. You can load it using `PropertiesPropertySourceLoader`.